# Resize Windows Console and MFC Static Library

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make this console program and it has to resize the console itself to put the text I want in it, so I used this method to resize it:

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
RECT r;
GetWindowRect(console, &r); //stores the console's current dimensions

MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, 775, 575, TRUE); // 775 width, 575 height

}
```

It works perfectly with the rest of my code. The only problem is that when I send my program to a friend it says "MSVCP140.dll" is missing in his PC.
So to fix this what I always do is change in Visual Studio's Project settings from "Use Standard Windows Libraries" to "Use Static MFC Library" and that way it won't ask for "MSVCP140.dll". The only problem here is that when I set it to Use Static MFC Library it throws this error:

```
Unresolved external symbol _imp_GetWindowRect
Unresolved external symbol _imp_MoveWindow
```

If I remove the Console resize command from above, it will work no problem. So the problem is basically that if I use the Console Resize I have to use Standard Library and if I don't I can use MFC Library. but I need to use the Console resize with the MFC so it doesn't ask for a .dll to open on other's computer.

I'm going crazy over here. Any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: Does your application use MFC or just the native Win32 APIs?

Comment: I don't even know. The source literally has #include <string> #include <iostream> #include <windows.h> and some system ("pause" ), some couts , getlines and that's just it (and the console resize thingy). I just want to make it so it doesn't ask for a MSVCP140.dll . That's it. (btw I don't know if this answers your question, but I'm new to this, hope it helps.

Comment: Then no, your application doesn't include a GUI which is what MFC is for.  See my answer.

Comment: How can I eliminate the program asking for "MSVCP140.dll" then? (Setting it to MFC libraries used to do the trick but not in this case). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're changing the wrong setting.  If you're not using MFC, leave the "Use of MFC" option at "Use Standard Windows Libraries".

Instead, look under "C/C++ / Code Generation" and change the "Runtime Library" option from "Multi-threaded DLL" to "Multi-threaded"

Similarly, in Debug mode, you'd switch from "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" to just "Multi-threaded Debug"

or

You could have your friend download & install the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: Hi, I just checked the code generation option and it's already at "Multi-threaded", and if I leave the "Use Standard Windows Libraries" it will still ask the person for MSVCP140.dll :/

Comment: @Aaron Did you switch it in both release & debug mode?  Not sure why switching the runtime library wouldn't work.  I'd double check the build output directory to ensure you're getting the right exe and use the [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com) program to verify if it worked

Comment: You were right Sir, It actually worked now that I double checked. Thank you very much.